# Can I use the referenceSearchCondition with an Enum Attribute?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I like to limit the results by value in my field in backoffice config file. **To mention is that my grouptype field is an ENUM**. Is it possible to do this? I tried already this in mybackoffice-config.xml:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="disableGroups">
     <editorArea:editor-parameter>
         <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_grouptype</editorArea:name>
         <editorArea:value>DISABLE_GROUP</editorArea:value>
     </editorArea:editor-parameter>
</editorArea:attribute>
```

but I get this ERROR:

```
    ERROR [hybrisHTTP30] [UiEngineImpl]
de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.UnknownIdentifierException: No attribute with qualifier grouptype found.
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.type.impl.DefaultTypeService.getAttributeDescriptor(DefaultTypeService.java:195) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.adjustCondition(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:214) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.adjustConditionRecursively(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:205) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.adjustConditionRecursively(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:198) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.parseSearchQueryAttributes(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:183) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.createSearchQueryDataBuilderWithAttributes(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:173) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.adjustSearchQuery(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:161) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.hybris.backoffice.cockpitng.dataaccess.facades.search.DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.searchInternal(DefaultPlatformFieldSearchFacadeStrategy.java:104) ~[classes/:?]
```

Second try:
I tried also with the sequence number of my ENUM value like this:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="disableGroups">
 <editorArea:editor-parameter>
     <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_grouptype</editorArea:name>
     <editorArea:value>3</editorArea:value>
 </editorArea:editor-parameter>
```

I get no errors but it doesn't work either. It does nothing.